# Change GoogleApps script to get from separate sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently using this script to get timestamp

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() == 'Subsidy Portions') {
    var colWatch = 6;      // column to watch, 5 = "E"
  var colRecord = 9;     // column for timestamp,  6 = "F"
  if (e.range.getColumn() == colWatch) {
    e.range.offset(0, colRecord - colWatch).setValue(new Date());
  }
  }}
```

however, now need to reference a different sheet within same file.

Need `colWatch = 2` on `Notes` sheet

and `colRecord = 9` on `Subsidy Portions` sheet

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, when Column 2 in the **Notes** sheet changes you want to add a timestamp to Column 9 in the **Subsidy Portions** sheet.  To do this, you add another IF() section as the code provided runs on every edit of the file (untested):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() == 'Subsidy Portions') {
    var colWatch = 5;      // column to watch, 5 = "E"
    var colRecord = 8;     // column for timestamp,  6 = "F"
    if (e.range.getColumn() == colWatch) {
      e.range.offset(0, colRecord - colWatch).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }

  if (s.getName() == 'Notes') {
    var colWatch = 2;      // column to watch, 5 = "E"
    var colRecord = 9;     // column for timestamp,  6 = "F"
    if (e.range.getColumn() == colWatch) {
      var sReceivingSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Subsidy Portions');
      var myRow = e.range.getRow();
      var editRange = sReceivingSheet.getRange(myRow, colRecord);
      editRange.setValue(new Date());

    }
  }

}
```

**Explanation**:

This s is set to be the active sheet, the one which was edited to trigger the function.  s.geName gets the name of that sheet and it is tested to see if the name matches the name for the code inside the {}.

```
if (s.getName() == 'Subsidy Portions') {
  // Code...
}
```

Inside the IF section for **Notes**, this loads the sheet named **Subsidy Portions** into sReceivingSheet, get the row which was edited in the **Notes** sheet, and assumes we are editing the same row in **Subsidy Portions**. It then uses that and the column to edit to get a range of a single cell, saving that in editRange, and then adds the new date to that cell.

```
var sReceivingSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Subsidy Portions');
var myRow = e.range.getRow();
var editRange = sReceivingSheet.getRange(myRow, colRecord);
editRange.setValue(new Date());
```

If you need to edit a different row in this second part, we need more code to find that row by getting all the data and looping through until will find the correct row.  I suggest looking at the getRowData() function in the sample code of [Tutorial: Simple Mail Merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge)